# pythonでの”shift-jisのbytes型”から”utf-8の文字列”への変換

Tags: python, python3

初歩的な質問です．python3でurllibを使ってhtmlのコードを取得しようとしています．

```
  request = urllib.request.Request(url)
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(request) 
  html = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

上記のようにソースコードを取得しています．取得先のページがutf-8でエンコードされているときはうまく取得できるのですが，shift-jisでエンコードされている場合

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 228: invalid start byte
```

とエラーが出ます．"bytes型のshift-jis"を"bytes型のutf-8"に変換してからデコードすればうまくいくと思うのですが，そういった方法は可能でしょうか．

Answer (score 1):

単純には`html = response.read().decode('ShiftJIS')`でいいですよね。

どのエンコーディングを使うかを決めるためには、httpのヘッダとか、html要素のlang属性とか、meta要素とか、考えられる限りの情報を見て判断しないといけませんが、そんなことをがんばるぐらいなら、[公式ドキュメント](http://docs.python.jp/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) に**書いてあるとおり**、Requests を使う方がいいと思いますよ。

Comment: 書き忘れていました．shift-jisを直接デコードしようとすると    `UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 533: illegal multibyte sequence`  とエラーが出ます．また，エンコーディングの種類については取得先のページは今回は固定なので大丈夫です．

Comment: すみません，解決しました．shift-jisではなくcp932でエンコードされていたようです

Comment: ShitJISでエンコードしていることになっているけれども、ShiftJISとして不正なシークェンスを含むページを読み込みたいということですか?（行き違いでした）